# Examples of Good Novel Blurbs?

Tags: novel, resources, marketing

I am trying to find examples of good novel blurbs that are both informative and engaging. I've looked back at some of my favorite novels and found their blurbs represented the contents poorly. Some were just plain all-round bad.

So... I'm curious if anyone remembers any blurbs that they thought were excellent. I would particularly like blurbs that manage to fit in some world building gracefully, but I would appreciate blurbs from any novel genre that are written particularly well.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm afraid that open-ended list questions of this nature are off-topic here.

Comment: Try here https://blog.reedsy.com/write-blurb-novel/